# Cancel the router navigation in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

How can I cancel the router navigation in a view controller in SAPUI5?
Sample: I will interrupt the back navigation when the input field's is not saved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing router from navigating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165700/preventing-router-from-navigating)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091125/5846045

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to use a Router-based navigation in SAPUI5. You can just skip it and use [sap.m.NavContainer](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html) methods directly. Furthermore you can catch the `navigate` resp. `afterNavigate` event to do more custom stuff if neccessary.

You could also do the following things on [sap.m.Page](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Page.html):

- attach on the `navButtonPress` event
- hide the nav button with `setShowNavButton(false)`
- use a custom header implementation thus you could dynamically enable/disable the back button. This way you need to implement back navigation by hand which shouldn't be to hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a backButton for the back navigation, you can check in the method (f.e. handleNavButtonPress) you call there whatever you would like to check.

```
handleNavButtonPress : function (oEvent) {
    //do your check here
    //nav back only if your check was ok
},
```