# Preventing router from navigating

Tags: sapui5

I need to prevent router to be navigated to another page (which is done by changing the hash) if some changes are made. Tried with HashChanger but it just fires 'hashChange' events with no way to prevent it from bubbling. The answer can be inside of JS-Signals library but it's unavailable directly for user-created SAP components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a stop function on the router https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router/methods/stop

if you call it, the router will stop listening to hashchanges.

There is also function isStopped().
To (re-)activate the router, call initialize(...).

Comment: Yeah, this definitely should work. I was implementing such behavior with extending Router.parse method, but will switch to this approach as more logical.

Comment: Unfortunately, approach with stopping controllers does not work as I expected. When I listening to 'hashChanged' events, router is also listening to this event. In this case, I need to stop the router BEFORE attaching event listener to 'hashChange' event (which is really uncomfortable), otherwise router will always deal with 'hashChange' before my handler. There is maybe a race condition too.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of stopping the router entirely, navigation can be prevented by `event.preventDefault()` within the [`navigate`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.NavContainer#events/navigate) event handler.

```xml
<App xmlns="sap.m" navigate=".onNavigate">
```

```js
onNavigate: function(event) {
  if (/* Pending changes, no authorization [1], etc. */) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { isBack, isBackToPage, isBackToTop } = event.getParameters();
    const isBackNavigation = isBack || isBackToPage || isBackToTop;
    window.history.go(isBackNavigation ? 1 : -1);
    // Inform the user ...
  }
},
```

- Demo: [https://embed.plnkr.co/wp6yes](https://embed.plnkr.co/wp6yes?show=view%2FApp.view.xml,preview)
- Further discussion about interrupting navigation: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3411

---

[1]: If the reason for preventing navigation is the lack of authorization, it's not enough to block the user on the client-side only. The server needs to make sure that no unauthorized resource is sent to the client in the first place. See the [response from @matz3](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3094#issuecomment-739891005) on GitHub.