# Route Guards in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

In SAP UI5 or OpenUI5 is it possible to restrict access to some routes? In other words, does UI5 provide any solution that works like Angular Route Guards?

Comment: Nope, for the routing inside the apps i am not aware of any standard way to achieve what you want to do. You may want to split the functionality for the different user groups into different apps.

Comment: Here I mentioned how the app can prevent navigation https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091125/5846045. But it cannot restrict users to launch the app with a deep link. What is the use case if I may ask? Is the app going to be deployed to FLP? Or is it a standalone app? Otherwise, I agree with @Erch. Splitting the app according to user roles might be more suitable.

Answer (score -1):

There is a stop function on the router https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router/methods/stop

if you call it, the router will stop listening to hashchanges.

There is also function isStopped(). To (re-)activate the router, call initialize(...).

Answer (score -1):

You could use the method `attachPatternMatched`. Inside the attached piece of code a simple check could restrict the access to the view when a condition is not met.