# Is there a way to make protected route in sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```
getRouter: function () {
        return UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
      },
onInit: function () {
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
     if (!user) {
       this.getRouter().navTo("login");
         }
        });
      }
```

Is there a way to make my routes protected, it is no problem when the first time I type in browser, I got redirected, but if I logout from the component, and manually type in browser  /admin, I am not redirected, so onInit works only one time. I am new to sapui5, and in React it is different. Can someone please help and explain if there is a way to make some kind of protection on routes. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing router from navigating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165700/preventing-router-from-navigating)

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091125/5846045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct event to listen for is [patternMatched](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Route#events/patternMatched)

This is an example of how to protect a single route called "myProtectedRoute":

```js
onInit: function () {
    this.getRouter().getRoute("myProtectedRoute").attachPatternMatched((event) => {
        if (user.isAuthenticated) {
           // load and show data
        } else {
           this.getRouter().navTo("login");
        }
    })
}
```

If you wish to be notified when any route is matched you can read more in this tutorial https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/4a063b8250f24d0cbf7c689821df7199