# How to stop and continue navigation SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to prevent dataloss by asking the user, if they want to safe or discard their changes when leaving the page with the back-button.

I have tried the following code:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('backBtn').attachPress(function (oEvent) { //react on backbutton press
            oRouter.stop(); //stop routing
            MessageBox.warning("you got pending changes", {
                actions: [MessageBox.Action.OK, MessageBox.Action.CANCEL],
                emphasizedAction: MessageBox.Action.OK,
                onClose: function (sAction) {
                    if (sAction == "OK") {
                    }
                    else if (sAction == "CANCEL") {
                        oRouter.initialize(true); //continue routing
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I also tried the following thing:

```
            let continue = false
            oRouter.stop(); //stop routing
            MessageBox.warning("you got pending changes", {
                actions: [MessageBox.Action.OK, MessageBox.Action.CANCEL],
                emphasizedAction: MessageBox.Action.OK,
                onClose: function (sAction) {
                    if (sAction == "OK") {
                    }
                    else if (sAction == "CANCEL") {
                        continue = true
                    }
                }                    
            });
            if(continue){
               oRouter.initialize(true); //continue routing 
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing router from navigating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165700/preventing-router-from-navigating)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091125/5846045